# orWhereHas not existing laravel Eloquent php 7.4

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

Here is my Macro for relation search in  Laravel Eloquent.
Bellow is my Macro in AppServiceProvider.php

```
    Builder::macro('whereLike', function ($attributes, string $searchTerm) {
        $this->where(function (Builder $query) use ($attributes, $searchTerm) {
            foreach (Arr::wrap($attributes) as $attribute) {
                $query->when(
                    str_contains($attribute, '.'),
                    function (Builder $query) use ($attribute, $searchTerm) {
                        [$relationName, $relationAttribute] = explode('.', $attribute);

                        $query->orWhereHas($relationName, function (Builder $query) use 
                    ($relationAttribute, $searchTerm) {
                            $query->where($relationAttribute, 'LIKE', "%{$searchTerm}%");
                        });
                    },
                    function (Builder $query) use ($attribute, $searchTerm) {
                        $query->orWhere($attribute, 'LIKE', "%{$searchTerm}%");
                    }
                );
            }
        });

        return $this;
    });
```

Bellow is my search Query in MemberController.php

```
 public function getMembers(request $request){

 $members = Member::with('products')->where('groupId', 1)->whereLike(['firstname', 
   'lastname', 'products.name'], $request->searchValue)->paginate(10);
dd($members);
}
```

The "whereLike" is invoked from the appServiceProvider.php as a macro in there thus where the error occur if i remove the `members.name` the macro executes perfectly.

I get an Error with orWhereHas

"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::orWhereHas()"

Comment: orWhereHas exist in laravel 7.x

Comment: Please help me with that. I followed laravel page and they discussed the bug but nothing helpfull for me maybe i did not understand am stuck here.

Comment: Can you please elaborate so far what you've tried with orWhereHas()?

Comment: I have not used it anywhere else in my project except now that i want to search through relations. I made the macro to help me so the macro is in AppServiceProvide.php so that in my controller i can query at a simplified code.

Comment: why your using `Builder $query` .? it should be model instance and query builder don't has relationship that's why this function is not in  `Builder` class

Comment: @Kamlesh Paul its easier. The builder works well. If you replace the `orWhereHas` with `whereHas` it runs perfectly but not what i require. The problem is only with `orWhereHas`

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? What does the error call stack look like?